Chromadb EOFError: Ran out of input
I'm using chromadb to save my vector embeddings.
The database was updating just fine for the last months. All of a sudden I am getting the following error:
EOFError: Ran out of input

The code below is the one causing the issue.
collection.add(
    documents=docs,
    metadatas=metadatas,
    ids=ids,
)

I am not sure where to begin debugging and fixing this.
Full error below:
File "/var/www/panoraapp.com/public_html/api/genius/search_embeddings.py", line 237, in save_to_chroma
    collection.add(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/chromadb/api/models/Collection.py", line 168, in add
    self._client._add(ids, self.id, embeddings, metadatas, documents, uris)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/chromadb/telemetry/opentelemetry/__init__.py", line 143, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/chromadb/rate_limiting/__init__.py", line 45, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/chromadb/api/segment.py", line 372, in _add
    self._manager.hint_use_collection(collection_id, t.Operation.ADD)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/chromadb/telemetry/opentelemetry/__init__.py", line 143, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/chromadb/segment/impl/manager/local.py", line 230, in hint_use_collection
    instance = self.get_segment(collection_id, type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/chromadb/telemetry/opentelemetry/__init__.py", line 143, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/chromadb/segment/impl/manager/local.py", line 217, in get_segment
    instance = self._instance(segment)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/chromadb/segment/impl/manager/local.py", line 246, in _instance
    instance = cls(self._system, segment)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/chromadb/segment/impl/vector/local_persistent_hnsw.py", line 107, in __init__
    self._persist_data = PersistentData.load_from_file(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/chromadb/segment/impl/vector/local_persistent_hnsw.py", line 70, in load_from_file

